# How to "browse" a site with a minitest integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, minitest

I am trying to write an integration test on rails which is supposed to visit my various pages but I can't get past the login.

```
    require 'test_helper'

class UserSimulationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest


  test "login site" do
    # login via https
    https!
    get "users/sign_in"
    assert_response :success

    post_via_redirect "users/sign_in", username: users(:User_1).email
    assert_equal "/users/sign_in", path

    https?
    assert_response :success
  end
  test "go to voting" do
    https!
    get "voting"
    post_via_redirect "users/sign_in", username: users(:User_1).email
    post_via_redirect "voting"
    assert_equal "/voting", path
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Then i get this error because it redirects me to the login again.

```
Minitest::Assertion: Expected: "/voting"
  Actual: "/users/sign_in"
test/integration/user_simulation_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:UserSimulationTest>'
Finished in 0.84105s
2 tests, 4 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Seems you have your app set to redirect unless you're logged in.  That means for every test you should login.  So extract the things you need to do to login to your test_helper.  Then you can call that method in each test where you need to be logged in.

Comment: But i already try logging in before going to the voting page. It still redirects me.

Comment: I put my login method in the test helper but I get redirected again. It makes not difference it seems.

Comment: Did you edit your question? You want login then got to voting.  You seem to be going to voting, then signing in then posting to voting.

Comment: It seems your sign in step is wrong and user isn't signed in. Recheck parameters in sign in's post request - usually you have to use standart  parameters schema and add model name like `user: {username: 'user-1-name'}`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by passing the correct username and password parameters from my fixtures. I am using devise so i created a login method in test_helper.rb

```
def login(user)
    post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => user.email, 'user[password]' => user.encrypted_password
  end
```